# Why was Yearling badge awarded twice 3 days apart?

Tags: discussion, badges

When I read it that *this badge can be awarded multiple times* I thought it means every year it will be awarded once to the active member.

But I see that my own badge is awarded twice and *only* 3 days apart.

Why?

[image: Yearling]

Answer (score 9):

If you are idle for two years and then return, each 200 reputation points appear to give you a Yearling badge until all of your unclaimed years are used up.

(I don't know this for a fact, but it's consistent with unexpected Yearling badges I have earned on sites which I visit only occasionally.)